# Can I install a Windows 8 App directly from the app store website?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

The online website for the Windows 8 App Store is still in the "preview" stage and doesn't support searching through for apps. However, if you have a direct link to an app (for example, from the [apptivate.ms](http://apptivate.ms/contest) contest), then you can view its information online, without having to open the Store app.

The problem is, once you're on the webpage, there's no way to actually install the app. No "install" button, no "add to my account" or "download" or anything. The only way (that I've seen) to install the app is to go into the Store app and search for the desired app by name, hunt through the list of results, and install it from there.

Is there any way to just download it directly from the Windows App Store website, or at least open the app in the Store app without having to search for it?

Comment: @Louis thanks for the link. I do already know how to search, it's just inconvenient to have to do it when I've got the app open right in front of me online.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the app link from Internet explorer, there's an option to view the app in Windows Store.

[image]

The same, however, is absent in Google Chrome.

[image]

So right now, the way to go about this is to search(on Google?) using Internet Explorer and then use the View in Windows Store option - no real alternative.

Comment: Hmm. I'd be interested to see what that link actually does. I wonder why it doesn't show up in other browsers.

Comment: I checked in IE, it's a button not any sort of link. Seems like there's some undocumented API weirdness going on.

Comment: @nhi there's a meta name declaration - `<meta name="MS.App.Id" content="ad0d96c9-d895-4be6-9967-26cad215d1ee" />` my best guess is that IE reads that and adds the relevant link. Other browsers haven't implemented it yet

Comment: There seams to be a `ms-windows-store:` protocol for this.

Comment: A google search for "MS.App.Id" returns no relevant results. Nor did a bing or MSDN search.

Comment: @nhinkle foudn this though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh781489(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @AkshatMittal that looks interesting. I can't get Chrome to open any `ms-windows-store:` links right now. Will have to find some more info on that.

Comment: @nhinkle Seams like Windows has blocked apps other than IE to use this protocol, launching this in 'Run' dialog opens up the Windows Store.

Comment: @nhinkle Just found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974767.aspx

Comment: @AkshatMittal I tried `ms-windows-store:` in Firefox and it worked. So maybe it's chrome's fault.