# How to download Windows 8 Apps from Windows Store?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install a Windows 8 App directly from the app store website?](https://superuser.com/questions/490924/can-i-install-a-windows-8-app-directly-from-the-app-store-website)

I am running Windows 8 on my laptop.

I want to download Skitch, so I visited [this page](http://evernote.com/skitch/), which gave me [this link](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-GB/app/skitch/95a8df2f-f779-4034-a995-82d8e723b246) to Windows 8 Store, but I am not able to find any link to download the software. What's Wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Are you visiting this page on a Windows 8 machine?

On Windows 8 you should see a button that upon clicking will open the Windows 8 store app. The button will appear only if you are browsing the page on a Windows 8 machine.

[image]

Alternatively, you can [search for the app in the Store](https://superuser.com/questions/434776/how-do-i-search-the-windows-8-store).

Comment: Thanks for fixing my edit. I assumed it required IE since it doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: Maybe OP uses Chrome as well, and that is why he did not see the button. Anyway, your suggestion to search the app in the store app itself will solve the problem either way.

Comment: Yes Louis, use Internet Explorer to browse the Microsoft Store.. Anyway Firefox works too.